# Logistic regression with spark ml (data frames)

Tags: python, pyspark, pipeline, logistic-regression, apache-spark-ml

I wrote the following code for logistic regression, I want to use the pipeline API provided by `spark.ml`. However it gave me an error after I try to print coefficients and intercepts. Also I am having trouble computing the confusion matrix and other metrics like precision, recall.

```
#Logistic Regression:
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.sql  import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer,VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator


sc = SparkContext("local", "predictive")
sqlContext=SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.load('/user/bna_ads_final.csv', 
                      format='com.databricks.spark.csv', 
                      header='true', 
                      inferSchema='true')

df.show(5)
df.count()
df.dtypes  
df=df.withColumn("load_date",df.load_date.cast("timestamp"))
df_withday= df.withColumn("day",dayofmonth(df.load_date))
df_new=df_withday.withColumn("Month",month(df.load_date))
df_new=df_new.withColumn("classname",df_new.classname.cast("string"))
ignore = ["load_date","wo_flag","serialnumber", "classname"]

def modify_values(r):
if r == "A" or r =="B":
    return "dispatch"
else:
    return "non-dispatch"

def show_metrics(metrics):
# Overall statistics
precision = metrics.precision()
recall = metrics.recall()
f1Score = metrics.fMeasure()
print("Summary Stats")
print("Precision = %s" % precision)
print("Recall = %s" % recall)
print("F1 Score = %s" % f1Score)
print (metrics.confusionMatrix())   

ol_val = udf(modify_values, StringType())
df_final = df_new.withColumn("wo_flag",ol_val(df_new.wo_flag))
indexer= StringIndexer(inputCol="classname", outputCol="classnamecat")
indexed = indexer.fit(df_final).transform(df_final)
indexed=indexed.withColumn("classnamecat",indexed.classnamecat.cast("int"))
indexed.show(5)
(trainingData, testData) = indexed.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[x for x in indexed.columns if x not in ignore],outputCol='features')
stringindexer=StringIndexer(inputCol="wo_flag", outputCol="labellr")
Classifier= LogisticRegression(labelCol="labellr", featuresCol="features")
pipeline=Pipeline(stages=[stringindexer,assembler,Classifier])
model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
predictions = model.transform(testData)

selected = predictions.select("features", "labellr", "probability", "prediction")
for row in selected.collect():
print row


evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(
labelCol="labellr", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="precision")
accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("Test Error = %g" % (1.0 - accuracy))
print("Accuracy= %g" % (accuracy))

print("Coefficients: " + str(model.coefficients))
print("Intercept: " + str(model.intercept))
```

The error that I get is :

```
print("Coefficients: " + str(model.coefficients))
AttributeError: 'PipelineModel' object has no attribute 'coefficients'
```

I have Spark 1.5 installed on the Hadoop cluster, I will not be able to upgrade anytime soon. Is there a work around to solve this issue.

```
load_date           |  r         |   classname| mstatus34_timdiff|  day|Month| classnamecat| serialnumber
+-----------+------------------+----------+--------------------+------------+--- +-----------+----
2013-12-29 10:55:...|non-dispatch|        6634|               19|    1|    7|         0.0| 231234     
2014-10-05 23:43:...|non-dispatch|        6634|                4|    5|   10|         0.0| 342345
2014-10-09 09:39:...|    dispatch|        5886|               36|    9|   10|         1.0| 563472
2014-09-16 09:47:...|    dispatch|        6634|               53|   16|    9|         0.0| 134657
```

Answer (score 4):

You can access individual stages using `stages` attribute of the `PipelineModel`

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression, LogisticRegressionModel
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

df = sc.parallelize([
    (0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0),
    (1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
]).toDF(["label", "x1", "x2", "x3"])

assembler = (VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(df.columns[1:])
    .setOutputCol("features"))

lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.01)

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[assembler, lr])
model = pipeline.fit(data)

[stage.coefficients for stage in model.stages if hasattr(stage, "coefficients")]
## [DenseVector([2.1178, 1.6843, -1.8338])]

## or

[stage.coefficients for stage in model.stages
    if isinstance(stage, LogisticRegressionModel)]
## [DenseVector([2.1178, 1.6843, -1.8338])]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer however this does not print the coefficients, it just gives me a blank brackets  : [ ]

Comment: Should work just fine as long as there is correct model in the pipeline. See the [mcve].

Comment: Hello @zero323 I have attached how the transformed data looks like, the model works fine when using an RDD and using lambda function with labeled points to make features and labels. But it fails on dataframes, My function of computing metrics and also printing coefficient doesnt work

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
pipeline=Pipeline(stages=[assembler, lr])
model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
lrm = model.stages[-1]

lrm.coefficients
```