# Converting Python to Scala in Spark ML?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

The question is about
[Logistic regression with spark ml (data frames)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278999/logistic-regression-with-spark-ml-data-frames)

When I want to change the code Python to Scala

Python:

```
[stage.coefficients for stage in model.stages
    if isinstance(stage, LogisticRegressionModel)]
```

Scala:(changed)

```
   for (stage<-model.stages){
        if(stage.isInstanceOf[LogisticRegressionModel]{
            val a = Array(stage.coefficients)
    }}
```

I have already checked `stage.isInstanceOf[LogisticRegressionModel]`, which  returned the True. However, `stage.coefficients` has the error message. It says `"value coefficients is not a member of org.apache.spark.ml.Transformer"`.

I only check the stage, it will return

```
org.apache.spark.ml.Transformer= logreg 382456482
```

Why the type is different when the isInstanceOf returns true? What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the type is different when the isInstanceOf returns true?

Well, Scala is a statically typed language and `stages` is an `Array[Transformer]` so each element you access is a `Transformer`. `Transformers` in general have no `coefficients`, hence the error.

> What should I do?

Be specific about the types.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel

model.stages.collect { 
  case lr: LogisticRegressionModel => lr.coefficients
}.headOption
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to ask one more question. It returns Some. How can I convert Some to Array?

Comment: It returns an `Option[o.a.s.mllib.linalg.Vector]`. If you're sure that required stage exists you could simply use `head` (instead of `headOption`) and `o.a.s.mllib.linalg.Vector` has `toArray` method.